# Why my grid seach isn't using splitted balanced batch?

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search

When I am using GridSearchCV on sklearn, it is outputting:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples
```

Isn't gridsearch using StratifiedKFold as for its cross-validation? Shouldn't it be using balanced batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridsearchCV will use `StratifiedKFold` depending on what `y` is. From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

> For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is
>   either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other
>   cases, KFold is used.

If `y` is a multi-label `KFold` will be used.

Comment: Ah I see, I missed that line there. I think I should balanced my data first.